Dismiss "jobs" sidebar highlight?

I'm probably missing something obvious, but how can I dismiss the highlight on Jobs here?

I saw that on the Staging Ground button. Clicking it and then refreshing the window did the trick, but I assume you already tried that?

@Anerdw I was able to get rid of the staging ground one via that method. I'm unsure if I had learned to ignore the jobs one and only noticed it by finding a way to dismiss the staging ground one, or what.

It seems quite inconsistent. I've yet to be able to get the staging ground one to go away, but jobs is gone.

I found the issue on my end, it seems the extra popup that goes with this indicator is blocked by a standard filter list. It’s dismissing the popup that gets rid of the indicator, not clicking the link. (Brave with no ad block addons and chrome with ublock origin)

Yeah I had to specifically click the cross in the "there are new badges" popup next to the staging ground menu item and then refresh the page before the highlight on it disappears. For the staging ground at least, I'm not sure what made the highlight on the jobs menu item disappear but I guess it was something similar.

Confirmed there is a bug for Jobs and a fix is in progress.
For staging ground, there are two popovers associated with the purple highlight.
The first popover is shown to new reviewers and it gets dismissed by either clicking to close the popover or visiting the staging ground page. In this case, if they dismiss the popover but haven't visited the page, the purple highlight will still exist.
The second popover is for our new staging ground badges. It gets dismissed by clicking to close the popover or the link inside the popover.

@Carrott "The second popover is for our new staging ground badges. It gets dismissed by clicking to close the popover or the link inside the popover." somebody just reported that the dismissal doesn't seem permanent: Possible to block the popup tips?

Please, further remove the highlight in the case where it only wastes the user's time. If I click on the highlighted "Jobs" link, it just tells me that it only works in the US. Thus, evidently the site knows I am not in the US; however, it still tries to draw me to click Jobs:

We're experimenting with ways to reintroduce Stack Overflow Jobs, a job site for technical job seekers. The current version of Jobs is available in the United States, but we'll be evaluating expansion to more countries.



I'm assuming you have an ad blocker turned on, otherwise you would see a small survey that aims to collect interest for job listings in other countries which may help us consider expanding.
